# Bootstrap grid without fixed height alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Without fixing the height of each row, how can I set the correct alignment of each next row element. 
Here is the code taken from basic bootstrap example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Small Grid</h1>
  <p>The following example will result in a 33.3%/66.6% split on small, medium and large devices. On extra small devices, it will stack (100% width).</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:blue;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, is the fiddle linke for the same https://jsfiddle.net/ujw59haf/1/
    Output is 
[image]

**I want that third element(blue colored div) should begin from left.** 
Here, I can use pull-left, but in actual scenario I have 6 elements over a row which is getting populated through web service and every element can have dynamic height.
Also, I cannot put elements of a row under a div and give some margin-bottom , as this will fix the number of elements in a row and when the screen size will change, elements of next row will begin from a new row and elements of next row will not be accomodated in previous one.

For the sake of clear understanding of my question , I am editing my question .

This is the fiddle for this updated code https://jsfiddle.net/0zevgop4/3/

Here , for larger screens , Field 4 always comes after Field 2 , as the height of Field 2 is more. 
[image]
I don't want to use row class, as this is hampering the editable fields structure.

Here is full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .wordWrap{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
  </style>
  <script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.editFields= false;
    $scope.ChangeStructure = function(){
        if($scope.editFields)
        $scope.editFields=false;
        else
        $scope.editFields=true;

    }
});

  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Small Grid</h1>



    <div class="row form-group bgColor" ng-hide="ActiveCustomer && (customerDetails.CustomerStatus != 'DUMMY' && customerDetails.CustomerStatus != 'DUMMY PENDING SETUP')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 1</label>
                    <div class="wordWrap">
                        <p>ABC Testing</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 6</label>
                    <div>
                        <p>Field</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="!editFields">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 2</label>
                    <div class="wordWrap">
                        <p>ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</p>
                    </div>                

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 3 </label>
                    <div ng-show="!editFields">
                        <p>XYZZZZZ</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight" ng-show="editFields">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="customerDetails.PhoneNumber" data-ng-mask="###-###-####" data-on="keyup" class="form-control" maxlength="12">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 4 </label>
                    <div class="wordWrap" ng-show="!editFields">
                        <p>PQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight" ng-show="editFields">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="customerDetails.MailAddress" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="!editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 5</label>
                    <div>
                        <p>MNOPPPPPP</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="IsAdmin">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 6</label>  
                    <div ng-hide="editFields">
                        <p>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</p>
                    </div>             

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="IsAdmin">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Field 7 <span ng-show="editFields" style="color:orangered;">*</span></label>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">
                        Field 2 Part 1<!--<span class="star-mark">*</span>-->
                    </label>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight">
                        <p>XYYYYY</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">
                        Field 2 Part 2
                    </label>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight">
                        <p>UIZZPTTTT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">
                        Field 2 Part 3
                    </label>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight">
                        <p>GGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">
                        Field 2 Part 4 
                    </label>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight">                       
                        <p>ABCDIGHGHGH</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-show="editFields">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">
                        Field 2 Part 5
                    </label>
                    <div class="dataMinHeight">
                        <p>ERTTTYYYYYYYY</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
  <div class="row"> 

    <button type="button"  ng-click="ChangeStructure()">
               Edit Fields
            </button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand the layout you're trying to achieve, but I think you just need to add another `<div class="row></div>` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ujw59haf/2/.

Comment: I don't want to use  class="row" , Please, see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Small Grid</h1>
    <p>The following example will result in a 33.3%/66.6% split on small, medium and large devices. On extra small devices, it will stack (100% width).</p>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="background-color:pink;">
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="background-color:blue;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
        </div>
        </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort,  but I don't want to use row class, Please see my updated question.